# send task to printer with php? (raspberry pi, cups)

Tags: php, pdf, printing, cups

i have a raspberry pi 2 server and want to print a pdf file using php code. I installed the printer with cups and the testprint works. However how can i send files with php to the printer now? Is there any command that sends a task to the printer?

Thank you!

Comment: CUPS emulates the traditional unix printing system, you should have the normal `lp` commands family available. That means you can simply do something like `system('lp -P myprinter /path/to/file.pdf');` Alternatively you can look for a native network client for CUPS, the IPP protocol is not really complex, that should not be difficult. When I last checked some years ago I fell back to the command line utilities, though.

Comment: thanks arkascha. One more question... what means lp and should i replace myprinter with the ip?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/lp